# Best way to cast numbers into strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, casting, numbers

Coming from a `C#` background, In `C#` I could write this:

```
int int1       = 0;
double double1 = 0;
float float1   = 0;

string str = "words" + int1 + double1 + float1;
```

..and the casting to strings is implicit. In `C++` I understand the casting has to be explicit, and I was wondering how the problem was usually tackled by a `C++` programmer?

There's plenty of info on the net already I know, but there seems to quite a number of ways to do it and I was wondering if there wasn't a standard practice in place?

If you were to write that above code in `C++`, how would you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings in C++ are just containers of bytes, really, so we must rely on additional functionality to do this for us.

In the olden days of C++03, we'd typically use I/O streams' built-in lexical conversion facility (via formatted input):

```
int    int1    = 0;
double double1 = 0;
float  float1  = 0;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "words" << int1 << double1 << float1;

std::string str = ss.str();
```

You can use various I/O manipulators to fine-tune the result, much as you would in a `sprintf` format string (which is still valid, and still seen in some C++ code).

There are other ways, that convert each argument on its own then rely on concatenating all the resulting strings. `boost::lexical_cast` provides this, as does C++11's `to_string`:

```
int    int1    = 0;
double double1 = 0;
float  float1  = 0;

std::string str = "words"
   + std::to_string(int1) 
   + std::to_string(double1) 
   + std::to_string(float1);
```

This latter approach doesn't give you any control over *how* the data is represented, though ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46a4eec82d7133a0)).

- [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)
- [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: Shouldn't we be closing this as an exact dupe rather than...?

Comment: @legends2k: That is not an exact dupe.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use Boost.LexicalCast (available for C++98 even), then it's pretty straightforward:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int int1       = 0;
    double double1 = 0;
    float float1   = 0;

    std::string str = "words" 
               + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(int1) 
               + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(double1) 
               + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(float1)
    ;

    std::cout << str;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff6b6a03255c09c0).

Note that as of C++11, you can also use `std::to_string` as mentioned by @LigthnessRacesinOrbit.

Answer (score 2):

Being a C developer, I would use the C string functions, as they are perfectly valid in C++, and let you be **VERY** explicit with respect to the formatting of numbers (ie: integers, floating point, etc).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

In the case of this, `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` is what you are looking for. The formats specifiers make it very obvious in the source code itself what your intent was as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to cast numbers into std::string in C++ is to use what is already available.
The library sstream provide a stream implementation for std::string.
It is like using a stream ( cout, cin ) for example

Its easy to use :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
   stringstream ss;
   string str;
   int i = 10;

   ss << i;
   ss >> str;

   cout << str << endl;     
}
```